# How is the user defined when using private cache in Google Apps Script?

Tags: caching, google-apps-script

Concerning private cache when using Google Apps Script the documentation says:
"Private caches are private to the current active user and script. They can be used to store information specific to that user."
My question is how is the user defined when using private cache in Google Apps Script?

Comment: could you refine your question ? is it a script in a document ? in a spreadsheet ? a webapp ? how is it deployed ? does it have triggers ? so many parameters are involved that you question is unanswerable ...

Comment: Yes, my script is inserted as a Gadget to a Google Sites web page, so I believe it would be deployed as a web app. There are no triggers. My client side script initially collects a user id that is validated by the server side script.  After the initial validation, I do not want the user to have to input their id again, even if they restart their browser window. Private caching appears to work for me, but I am just trying to understand the mechanics prior to fully committing. I have numerous simultaneous users, and I want to be sure to keep everything straight and in order.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just wrote an script that relied on the private cache service, and deployed it to execute it as myself while open to anyone (even anonymous) as a Web app. My understanding of is that widgets on Google Sites are essentially Web apps. I confirmed that when a script is deployed to execute as you (the owner), you are the "effective" user. However, the individual using the app (anonymous or not) is the active user. All active users gets their own private cache for that app, even if they're not the effective user. Here's the script I ran:

[Name Your Stooges](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGXaXQKSM_fwGooi-OQXDe9L8dtTs5pko3shXQY1efuktRixwv/exec)

If you had access to my private cache, you'd see my three stooges when you started the app (Anabel, Leopold, Walt), as well as my email address. But since it's a **private** cache, you won't: you'll have your own.

Comment: Thanks Richard. My script works like yours. However, my question is how is the active user identified by the server? Is it through cookies, browser login, NSA look-up tables, or what? Larry